# Do i need to place my App in Windows Store to avail WNS Service?

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml

Scenario:

I'm building a Windows 8 App which is outside of Windows Store. Here I wish to receive notifications using WNS. I have a Publisher which will generate events based on the user action on UI (Ex: Like Uploading a file, Once file upload is completed the event will be generated). I created a internal WCF Service(End Point) which will subscribe to the publisher and listens to the notifications sent by the Publisher. I'm integrating my Listener to WNS service in turn, once notifications are received by the listener, in turn will be sent to WNS Service to process and deliver to specific Device.

Here my question is in order to avail WNS service , do I need to keep my app in Windows Store ?? Is it mandatory ???

And Is their any way to implement push notifications in Windows 8 without using WNS Service????

Please clarify me on this.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Karthik Vadla

Answer (score 0):

An app that needs to use the Windows Push Notifications Service (WNS) will also need to be present in the store.  For an app to use WNS, it needs to register with the store app portal, which provides an app with a package security identifier (SID) and secret key, which are required to authenticate with and use WNS.

Windows Store Apps that need push notifications can only use WNS.

Traditional desktop applications are not able to use WNS, although they could implement their own version of push notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the information Nathan Kuchta.!!

Here i'm developing an app for my customer..i don't have any plan to keep it on store..!!
So, Their is no way to avail WNS without keeping it Store right.??

Is their any other way to implement this push notification in my Windows 8 app which is not going to be on the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use WNS in an unpackaged app: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/334